# UIScrollViews and Adding Components on them

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview

I need to add buttons to a `UIScrollView` so that it appears on all screens when you scroll. However a `UIScrollView` is just a view and not a controller therefore i cant add components to it. What is the best method to approach this? I can add the buttons on the subviews which are viewcontroller views however thats a little too much work and i was thinking maybe not the best option. How can i simply add one button the the `UIScrollView` view and use it universally for all its views?

Comment: What does the button do? Is it performing different actions for different views or it's action is irrespective of the views ?

Comment: Its the same action for all the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIView 
Add UIScrollView as subView
Then Add a UIButton to UIView on top of UIScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `UIView` and make the `UIScrollView` a subview of it.  Then add the components to the `UIView` too.